# Infinite recursion and sys.setrecursionlimit stops script without any errors

Tags: python, recursion, crash, exit, infinite-recursion

I wanted to do a few little experiments via measuring runtimes, especially comparing three implementations of fibonacci: recursive, lru_cache and linear (with linear space). I accidentally implemented the lru_ache version in a way that created infinite recursion:

```py
@lru_cache(None)
def fibo_cache(n):
    return fibo_cache(n)
```

(basically I wanted to reuse the recursive version first, but then I found that it would not apply cache to recursive calls, so changed it to this)

**This caused my program to just simply stop without any errors or messages.** If launched from IDLE, it created `RESTART: Shell` lines and go back to REPL

On the [documentation page of lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) I found no menntion of stopping the script.

Is this the intended behaviour, or a possible bug?

### EDIT:

I've set the recursion limit to 500_000 via sys. I'd still expect an exception, however. It's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) says

> This should be done with care, because a too-high limit can lead to a crash.

But does not say I'll get no message. This might be the case, however.

Comment: Did you change the recursion limit in `sys`?

Comment: @superbrain rain edited question